# Solve the stochastic differential equation $dX_t = -X_t \, dt + e^{-t} \, dW_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Solve the SDE

$$ dX_t=-X_tdt + e^{-t}dW_t $$

where $W_t$ is a standard  Brownian process.

IC: $X(0)=X_0$.

Comment: What did you try? Have you looked at $d(e^tX_t)$?

Comment: `Reynolds number`, from Osborne Reynolds, not "Reynold's number".

Comment: @Did Reynolds number...? Sure that this comment is related to this question?

Comment: @saz No, but to the OP's profile (now corrected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us first forget about the stochastic part "$e^{-t} \, dW_t$" and consider the ordinary differential equation

$$dX_t = - X_t \, dt, \qquad X_0 = c$$

instead. It is well-known (and not difficult to check) that the (unique) solution is given by

$$X_t = c e^{-t}.$$

In order to solve the SDE we are interested in, we now try a variation of constants approach, i.e. we let the constant $c$ depend on $\omega$ and $t$;  that is we set

$$X_t(\omega) = C_t(\omega) e^{-t} \tag{1}$$

for a suitable stochastic process $(C_t)_{t \geq 0}$. We have to check whether there exists a suitable process $(C_t)_{t \geq 0}$ such that $(1)$ solves the SDE

$$dX_t = -X_t \ dt + e^{-t} \, dW_t \tag{2}$$

To show that this is indeed true (and to determine $C_t$), apply Itô's formula to $C_t = e^t X_t$.