# SDE $dX_t= f(t)X_t dt + g(t) dW_t$

Tags: probability, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $T>0$
- $(W_t)$ is a standard brownian motion adapted to the filtration
- $f : [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}  $ in $L¹([0,T])$
- $g: [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ in $ L^2([0,T])$
- $R_t= \int_{0}^t \exp \left( - \int_{0}^{r} f(s) ds \right) g(r) dW_r$
- $Y_t= \exp \left(  \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds \right)  R_t$  $(\star)$

$
 \begin{cases}
      dX_t &= f(t)X_t dt + g(t) dW_t\\
      X_0  &= 0\\
    \end{cases}    
$

1. Show that $R$ is well-defined
2. Show that $Y$ is a gaussian process
3. Show that $ t \mapsto \int_{0}^t f(s) ds$ has bounded variations
4. Show that if $X$ is defined as $(\star)$, then $X$ solves the SDE
5. let $X$ be a solution of the SDE, show that $X=Y$
6. Can we use the usual theorems of existence and uniqueness ?

We want to solve the previous stochastic differential equation below.

---

1. $\int_{0}^{T} g(r) dW_r$ is a gaussian random variable with law $\mathcal{N}(0, {\lVert g \rVert}_2 ^2)$ because $g$ is square integrable.

Let $\phi(r)=\exp \left( - \int_{0}^{r} f(s) ds \right) g(r)$,

we have $\phi(r)^2=\exp( - 2 \int_{0}^r f(s) ds) g(r)^2 \leq \exp(  2 {\lVert f \rVert}_1 ) g(r)^2 $

therefore $\int_0^T \phi(r)^2 dr \leq \exp(  2 {\lVert f \rVert}_1 ) {\lVert g \rVert}_2 ^2$

so $R_t$ is well-defined.

2. $R_t$ si a gaussian process,it is a Wiener integral, then we multiply by a deterministic function.
3. $ \psi :t \mapsto \int_{0}^t f(s) ds$ has for derivative $f$ and the total variation $TV(\psi)= \int_{0}^T \mid \psi' \mid =\int_{0}^T \mid f \mid$ and we know that $f \in L^1$
4. We use Ito formula

$
\begin{align*}
d(\exp \left(  \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds \right)  R_t ) &=d(\exp \left(  \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds \right) ) R_t  +\exp \left(  \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds \right) dR_t +[\exp \left(  \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds \right), R]_t \\
&= f(t)\exp \left(  \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds \right) R_t+\exp \left(  \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds \right) \exp \left( - \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds \right) g(t)dW_t \\
&= f(t)Y_t +g(t) dW_t \\
\end{align*}
$

5. done below

**6. ????**

Answer (score 1):

Following  [the enhanced Hull-White equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619629/solving-of-enhanced-hull-white-dx-t-fracet-x-tt-2dt-tdw-t?rq=1) and [the constant variation method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021904/solve-the-stochastic-differential-equation-dx-t-x-t-dt-e-t-dw-t/2022264#2022264)

we solve $dZ_t=f(t) Z_t dt$ so $Z_t=c e^{ \int_0^{t} f(s)ds }$, then we solve, with the method of the constant variation :

$
\begin{align*}
X_t&= C_t e^{ \int_0^{t} f(s)ds } \\
C_t&= X_t e^{- \int_0^{t} f(s)ds } \\
dC_t&=- f(t) e^{- \int_0^{t} f(s)ds } X_t + f(t) X_t e^{- \int_0^{t} f(s)ds }
\left( f(t) X_t dt + g(t) dW_t \right) \\
dC_t &= - f(t) e^{- \int_0^{t} f(s)ds } X_t+  f(t) X_t e^{- \int_0^{t} f(s)ds } dt +  e^{- \int_0^{t} f(s)ds }  g(t) dW_t    \\
dC_t &=  e^{- \int_0^{t} f(s)ds }  g(t) dW_t  \\
C_t &= \int_0^{t} e^{- \int_0^{r} f(s)dr }  g(t) dW_t\\
X_t &=  e^{ \int_0^{t} f(s)ds } \int_0^{t} e^{- \int_0^{r} f(s)dr }  g(t) dW_t   \\
\end{align*}
$

$$\fbox{$X_t =  e^{ \int_0^{t} f(s)ds } \int_0^{t} e^{- \int_0^{r} f(s)dr }  g(t) dW_t  $ }$$